# Typescript: serialize JSON-lists

Tags: angular, typescript

This is how I today deserialize JSON-lists into object-lists.

```
export class StrLst
{
  public lst : Array <string> = new Array <string> ();

  public deserialize (input : any) : StrLst
  {
    for (let i = 0; i < input.length; i ++)
    {
      this.lst.push (input [i]);
    }
    return this;
  }
}



let lst : StrLst = new StrLst().deserialize(["abc", "def"]);
```

Is there a way I can get rid of the loop in `deserialize`?

I think about making `deserialize` static and returning an allocated `Array` instead of a wrapping the item-class (`StrLst`). Is that a good idea or are there some cons? I would prefer a collection instead of a wrap.

```
public static deserialize (input : any) : Array <string>
{
     let ret : Array <string> = new Array <string> ();
     ...
     return ret;
}

let lst : Array <string> = StrLst.deserialize (["abc", "def"]);
```

**EDIT**: Deserialisation of JSON is a common task and a lot of JSON is in lists. So I am looking for a common and elegant design for it. For deserializing non-lists I am using Object.assing. But for simplicity here I just used strings in the sample.

**EDIT**: I tried to make the sample easy. I need to deserialize because the elements of the JSON-lists normally are not strings but something more complex. And the JSON is also the response of a HTTP-request and not hardcoded.

Comment: Could you provide a bit more information as to the purpose of this? Looks like you are making a copy of an array? Or is `input` something other than an array?

Comment: In my sample input is always an array. Not always of strings but then I use Object.assign to deserialize.

Comment: @chris01 Are you sure what "serialize" means? Because mere data manipulation (which is what it looks like you're doing) is not serialization.

Comment: I also wonder if there's a reason for this - can't you simply do something like `const list: Array<string> = [...originalArray]`? That's if you really need a copy?

Comment: what are you trying to do ? `["abc", "def"].map(v => JSON.parse (v))` ?

Comment: I try to get objects (not Object) from JSON data. In my case the JSON is on the top layer a list. My sample calls of derserialize are only examples. Normally there would be the output of a http-client-response.

Answer (score 0):

Deserialization is the process of transforming a data source into a structured object.
If you are trying to achieve such, you can use `JSON.parse(data: string)`, which takes a JSON string and transform it into a JSON object.

In that sense, a serialized JSON list would look like 
 
`"[ jsonObject1, jsonObject2, jsonObject3, ...]"` (as a string), or even 
 
`"[ {object1Attribute: value}, {object2Attribute: { innerAtt: innerValue } }, {object3Attribute: [ innerJsonObj1, innerJsonObj2 ]} ]"`

And deserializing the latter string will generate the object:

```
[ 
  {
    object1Attribute: value
  }, 
  {
    object2Attribute: { 
      innerAtt: innerValue 
    } 
  }, 
  {
    object3Attribute: [ 
      innerJsonObj1, 
      innerJsonObj2 
    ]
  } 
]
```

Your function `deserialize` is not in fact deserializing some data, but transforming any iterable in a string array.
You can read more about JSON.parse [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse).

Comment: As you see this risks being mistaken for a clarification question. If you intend it to be an answer in the shape of a rethorical question, then you need to rephrase. Also, have a look here, it might have helpful info for you. https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help